# Scheduled Tasks with Quartz - JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc, quartz-scheduler

I'm trying to make a mini web application for reminders, I deploy Quartz Scheduler to handle the issue of launch events reminder, I have understood the tasks (Jobs) and programmers (Schedulers) can be configured from a Database with JDBC, I have searched and can not find an example where I show what information should I put on the tables and I run java code to start operating scheduled tasks. If someone can have an example or something that I can serve this purpose, they are grateful.

Comment: Are you really required to us the db for storing the schedules ? A conf file properly configured is all you need really.

Comment: yes, i require, there are several scheduled tasks that will over time, or what other way is there to do?

Answer (score 0):

You have understood wrong. You can use any JobStore (including the JdbcJobStore to store your jobs/triggers/etc. but creating them manually in the database is **a bad idea™**.

Depending on how you are using Quartz you can set it up, either using SPRING or using the Fluent syntax (which I believe is the preferred method these days).

Further reading: http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.1.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-09

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I will carefully read the tutorial lesson 9, let me get this right.